# How do I know which AJAX Requests are happening concurrently?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

A bit new to performance testing and web architecture in general, but when looking at AJAX Requests that are being called, how do I know which ones being called at the same time versus ones that aren't? Some of them I can see on developer tools being called like :

"Queued 1.50s" for two AJAX requests. If it's like a .01s difference does that mean they aren't called at the same time? I'm trying to figure out which ones I will need to put underneath a parallel controller in JMeter to create the correct network path.

Answer (score 0):

Requests have the same start time are "happening concurrently", like red rectangle in the below image of the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

[image]

others are sequential.

"Queued" mean that browsers open up to 6 concurrent connections per domain for [downloading embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) and/or executing AJAX requests so if your page has more than 6 AJAX requests defined only 6 of them will be executed at a time, others will be put into the queue.